# Alias to Previous Macro-Created Class

Tags: c++, c++17

## Background:

I am trying to build a registry of objects, but every object is templated by some value, e.g. int Parameter.

```cpp
template<int Parameter>
class SomeObject
{
// things
}
```

I have built a macro to register them

```cpp
#define REGERISTER_OBJECT(PREFIX,OBJECT)\
class reg_##PREFIX\
{\
 template<int Parameter>\
using Name = OBJECT\
template<int Parameter>\
void Register()\
{\
ObjectRegistry<Parameter>::Register<Name>();\
}
```

where `ObjectRegistry<Pameter>` is really just a templated version of https://www.bfilipek.com/2018/02/factory-selfregister.html

Now the trick is that I only want to build a registry for specific parameters. (Note, we can assume that the Parameter is only going to take one some values (e.g. 1,2,3).  However, in any one project I am only going to need one of them.)

Every time I try to make this work.  I run into one of three problems:

1. Nothing instantiates and the registry is empty.
2. Everything instantiates and there is an absurd memory requirement to compile.
3. I require a virtual template function  (if you attempt to derive reg_##PREFIX from some base class) and nothing compiles.

## The Question:

The best way to make this work is if there were a way to write a macro like this:

```cpp
#define REGERISTER_OBJECT(PREFIX,OBJECT)\
class reg_##PREFIX\
{\
using Previos = CLASS_CREATED_LAST_TIME_THIS_MACRO_WAS_INVOKED;
 template<int Parameter>\
using Name = OBJECT\
}
```

I can build a recursive function to register everything then. (I believe.)  However, there seems to be no way to hold data from the last invocation (i.e. in a #define).  Any way around this?

Comment: Do you want variadic MACRO: `#define REGERISTER_OBJECT(PREFIX, ...)` with `__VA_ARGS__` as OBJECT, and then "iterate" over them.

Comment: Then it's not automatic registration then.  AI could just throw all the names in an .hpp file and be done with it.